# Change E-commerce Company Name

Tags: virtocommerce

I want to use `virto commerce` in our start-up business with community license. Hence I want to put our company name in all pages of the virto commerce. How that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by modifying liquid themes through Commerce Manager. Go to Content->Store->Themes->Edit Html and open snippets/footer.liquid.

[image]

There you will find powered by link, you can add your company name next to it. To remove it completely you'll need a production community license, which you can request from virtocommerce.com site.

Comment: Seems very rude to delete answer that YOU don't understand.

Comment: @Woland: Deleting an answer which is nothing more than "You can change name inside theme." is perfectly acceptable. However, now than you've expanded upon the answer, it is also perfectly acceptable for it to be undeleted, as you have done.